# Which one of these is the best to use and why?

Tags: java, sql

I was doing an assignment and had an update class which accepted the SQL and updated table. I am using Java. I did it this way

```
sqls = "INSERT INTO statistics(ID, TeamName, Wins, Draws, Losses, Points, DatePlayed) VALUES ( 0 ,'"+var1+"',"+var2+","+var3+","+var4+","+var5+",'"+ date +"')";
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
 con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/players","root", "123");
 stmt = con.prepareStatement(sqls);
 int updaterows = stmt.executeUpdate(sqls);
```

my teacher did it this way

```
sqls = "INSERT INTO statistics(TeamName, Wins, Draws, Losses, Points, DatePlayed) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?)"
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/players","root", "123");
stmt = con.prepareStatement(sqls);
stmt.setString(1, var1);
stmt.setInt(2, var2);
stmt.setInt(3, var3);
stmt.setInt(4, var4);
stmt.setInt(5, var5);
stmt.setTimestamp(6, var6);
int updaterows = stmt.executeUpdate();
```

which one is better and why please it really got me confused as both methods worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitely use the second way - the teacher's way. Your way is very dangerous, because the code is prone to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Any person could enter `DROP DATABASE` as `TeamName` and your database will be gone.

P.S Some fun - [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: thx alot i asked because the teacher didn't tell me why to use second

Answer (score 4):

The teacher's way is better because it prevents an [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack.

Answer (score 2):

The second way is better (teacher`s way) in many aspects:

Security:

It prevents sql injection attacks. 
Reference: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java

Scalability:

It prevents excessive memory usage caused by repetitive string concatenation.
Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2431/abebf.html#abebh

Performance:

It allows database to create prepared statements (pre-compiled sql queries).
Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Maintainability:

It allows type checking of sql parameters at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

both ways you will get your job done, the 2nd way is better because it is more secure and prevents sql injection. But i want to point 1 thing which everyone skipped, the use of prepared statement, PreparedStatement calls are pre-compiled and gives better performance.

If a statement is used multiple times in a session, precompiling it provides better performance than sending it to the database and compiling it for each use. The more complex the statement, the greater the performance benefit.
If a statement is likely to be used only a few times, precompiling it may be inefficient because of the overhead involved in precompiling, saving, and later deallocating it in the database.

Also, i would advice you to check CallableStatement, you can create a stored procedure and put your SQL query inside it and run your stored procedure using CallableStatement. Callable Statement gives even better performance since it runs totally on database(if you have a remote database, and your network is slow, you will notice the performance) and also better security.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd version uses query parameters and is safer from a SQL-injection standpoint. Google SQL Injection for more details.